# I would like the code for button that starts at a certain number in android using android-studio

Tags: android

I would like to design a code in Android using Android Studio for button that starts at a certain number E.G: 20 and whenever the user clicks it decreases until 0. Something like this but a button that decreases the number Something like this

[image: Picture]

Thanks for anyone's help in advance.
Edit: Java is the programming language

Comment: What language are you using, Java or Kotlin? Can you provide some more details?

Comment: I plan to use Java

Comment: Could you please share what you've done so far so that others can help you find problems if any?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The xml file:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_start_view_16"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_start_view_16">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="20"
            app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Your activity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val button: Button by lazy { findViewById<Button>(R.id.button) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout)

  //      This is by no means the best way to do this, it is just for you to 
 //       have a point to start.

        button.setOnClickListener { it as Button
            val currentValue = it.text.toString().toInt()
            it.text = (currentValue - 1).toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your layout file should look like this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_start_view_16"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/margin_start_view_16">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="100"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

your activity file should look like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity() {
    int increment = 100;
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_layout)

     Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
     button.setText(increment);

    button.setOnClickListener(v->{
       increment--;
        v.setText(increment);
     );
}
```

This is just a simple implementation in java , but you can implement this better with
`databinding`.